# While Loop... Ruby syntax

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I am currently just trying to wrap my head around this example question. I don't understand the syntax of it. I don't understand the point of `i` and how it relates to `result`

```
def pow(base, exponent)
  result = 1
  i = 1 
  while i <= exponent
    result = result * base
    i += 1
  end
  result 
end
```

Any explanation much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

while need a do `while(i <= exponent) do`

*i* is a counter, you can replace the while for

```
exponent.times { result = result * base }
```

this code will execute the number (*exponent*) times the content of { }

And the *result* on end is the result of function, in ruby if you don't put a **return** clause will return the last line executed

Comment: Actually `while` doesn't need a do.

Comment: @Jesper: it needs *some* way to tell it, where the condition ends and the loop body begins. There are two ways, either the keyword `do` or an expression separator (newline or `;`). So, if you want to write it on one line and hate semicolons, then `do` is your only option. Adding it never hurts, but doing so when it is not required (as in this case) is un-idiomatic.

Comment: @JörgWMittag What made you think that I wasn't aware of that? I was simply refuting the clearly incorrect statement that a `while` needs a `do`.